# Mongodb - How to update a nested Array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have to update an Array nested in another Array.
Is it possible to do that with the $addtoset operator?

Here is my document.
I have a library wich has an Array of authors who have an Array of Books.

In this exemple, i'd like to add a new category to the book id 1 of the author id 1

How can i do that ?

```js
{
    "id" : NumberLong(666),
    "library" : [ 
        {
            "id" : NumberLong(8888),
            "author" : [ 
                {
                    "id" : NumberLong(1),
                    "books" : [ 
                        {
                "id":1,
                            "title" : "plop",
                            "category" : ["horror"],
                            "isbn" : 12345
                        }, 
                        {
                "id":2,
                            "title" : "plup",
                            "category" : ["comics"],
                            "isbn" : 6789
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "id" : NumberLong(2),
                    "books" : [ 
                        {
                "id":3,
                            "title" : "blop",
                            "category" : ["horror"],
                            "isbn" : 96325
                        }, 
                        {
                "id":4,
                            "title" : "blup",
                            "category" : ["comics"],
                            "isbn" : 74125
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this :

```js
db.library.update(
    {"id":666,"author.id":1,"books.id":1},
    {"$addToSet": {"author.$.books.category": "humour" }}
)
```

But it doesn't works

How does it works ?

thanks a lot

Comment: Change "id" --> "_id" and retry...

Comment: Hi, it's a mistake, it should be "id" and not "_id". I've modified the code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    db.library.update(
       {"id":666,"library.author.id":1,"library.author.books.id":1},
      {"$addToSet": {"library.0.author.0.books.$.category": "Book"}}
     )
```

Comment: Hi achuth, 

thanks for answer but it doesn't work. 
It doesn't return any error, but no category was added. 
Why ? Because the "select" condition 

    {"id":666,"author.id":1,"books.id":1} 

does not return any value. 
I've modified your request like This : 

    db.library.update( 
    {"id":666,"library.author.id":1,"library.author.books.id":1}, 
    {"$addToSet": {"library.$.author.$.books.$.category": "humour" }} ) 

but an error is returned: **can't append to array using string field nam [$]**

Comment: I didn't see the documentation that positional operator supports only one level, if you know the index of the array you can insert upto three levels {$push:{"a1.0.a2.$.a3":{a3id:2, a4:"other data"}} shown in [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/oURHV3jYS1s)

Comment: {"$addToSet": {"library.0.author.0.books.$.category": "achuth"}}
 ), this will work if you know the array index

Comment: Thanks for answer,

Ok, i didn't want to believe on it...
So the only solution is to select elements which must be updating, and then browse the results's list and execute an update for each elements's list.
My wish was to do the update on one query without list browsing.
I didn't find any documentation describing this limitation, thanks for your links's reference

Comment: Check this for reference http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays

Comment: Thanks achuth, i spent a long time to search and the answer was under my eyes ... thanks a lot